# How to make a reference to an instance statusBar (tkinter) from another class in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, statusbar, python-3.5, object-reference

I need some help understanding and solving a small program. I have taken a small piece of code from a forum. This code creates a GUI by using tkinter library.

The application consist of 3 classes, App_main, StatusBar and Report. In the App_main class a statusBar instance is created and the colour, text can be modify by invoking the StatusBar class and methods.

I can create a new StatusBar instance in the report class, but I want to resuse the instance create in App-main class.

The question how can I change name/colour of this instance(statusBar) from the Report class? How to make a reference to that object, so it can be modify from any other class?.Thanks a lot.

```
from ipywidgets import *
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
import time

class App_main(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="black")
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.minsize(width=500, height=300)
        self.parent.maxsize(width=500, height=300)

        # Tool Bar #
        toolbar = Frame(self.parent, bg="black")
        connect_button = Button(toolbar, text="Connect", activebackground='grey', width=20, borderwidth=3, command=self.main_test)
        connect_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=8, pady=8)
        toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        label = Label(self.parent, text='copy statusbar')
        label.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        # Statusbar
        self.status = StatusBar(self.parent)
        self.status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        print(self.status)
        print('status ->', id(self.status))
        print(type(self.status))

    def get_st(self):
        return self.status

    def main_test(self):

        self.status.setColour('white')
        print("...")
        print("Starting main test...")
        self.status.set("Starting main test...")
        sleep(2)
        print("...")
        self.status.set('finishing testing...')
        sleep(2)
        self.status.set('Test done...')
        sleep(1)

        rep = Report(self.parent)
        rep.making_report()


class Report(App_main):

    def making_report(self):
        st = StatusBar(self.parent)
        st.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        st.set('creating report')
        print('creating report')


# Status bar class #
class StatusBar(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = Label(self, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
        self.label.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    def set(self, format, *args):
        self.label.config(text=format % args)
        self.label.update_idletasks()

    def setColour(self, format, *args):
        self.label.config(bg=format % args)
        self.label.update_idletasks()

    def clear(self):
        self.label.config(text="")
        self.label.update_idletasks()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Tk()  # root
    App_main(app)
    app.config(background="black")
    app.title("app test")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Create an object of the class you want to make a reference to in the current class.

Comment: Hi Parviz. Thanks for you answer. I have created an object type Statusbar in the class App_main-- self.status = StatusBar(self.parent)--. Now I want  to call this object but from the class Report, so I can use modify its text. Do you have any suggestiion?. Thanks